# compare dataframes and extract matching rows

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I have two dataframes (e.g., A and B) of different lengths and am attempting to extract the duplicate values between them.

The below is just a toy dataset because my real datasets are much longer:

```
A <- data.frame(c('g','f','a', 'e'))
B <- data.frame(c('a','b','c', 'd', 'e'))
```

Here the matching values between A and B are: `a` and `e`

I've attempted to use the `library(comparison)` but have only been able to check whether there are duplicates and if so, how many. Instead, I'd like to know *which* values are the duplicates. Non-working code below:

```
comparison <- compare(A,B,allowAll=TRUE)
comparison$tM
```

Comment: `intersect(A$col, B$col)` ?

Comment: @RonakShah Oh that's perfect!! Thanks, I was guessing that it'd be something simple!